# Configuration email server from multiple domain names

Tags: server, dns, email, postfix, vps

I have one VPS server and 4 domains under that, having 1 IP address as of now, also I have 4 CloudFlare accounts for 4 domains hosted for easier DNS management

My question is:

Q1. Is it possible to configure server such that same IP resolves to multiple domains but sending email resolved to different domain name?
Example: When user with email ID `abc@domain1.com` sends mail to someone it should be shown as send by and signed by `domain1.com`, this will be same for other domains.

- `abc@domain1.com` -> send and signed by `domain1.com`
- `abc@domain2.com` -> send and signed by `domain2.com`
- `abc@domain3.com` -> send and signed by `domain3.com`
- `abc@domain4.com` -> send and signed by `domain4.com`

Though I have configured postfix settings in the `main.cf` file located in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, but here I just managed to change the `hostname` for once and for all domains. I mean it is an error because whenever mail is send through different domain it is still shown as send with `domain1.com`:

- `abc@domain1.com` -> send and signed by `domain1.com`
- `abc@domain2.com` -> send and signed by `domain1.com` (Note: it is signed by different domain)
- `abc@domain3.com` -> send and signed by `domain1.com` (Note: it is signed by different domain)
- `abc@domain4.com` -> send and signed by `domain1.com` (Note: it is signed by different domain)

Here last 3 mail send resolves to `domain1.com`, which clearly is an error.

Q2. Do I have to buy new IP address for each domain I want to host at this VPS for correct resolution, does this solves hostname problem? Is this a possible solution?
How can I manage to get different Hostname for different IP. Do this have any relation to rDNS?

Q3. Is there a way to dynamically assign the hostname based on IP address/sending domain?

I have edited the `main.cf` file located in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` using SSH, added the lines:

```
myhostname = domain1.com
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
```

I have managed to successfully resolve all the DNS issues like DKIM signature, SPF record etc., but there are other 3 domains also there, but all the hostname resolves to `domain1.com` even though email sent using other domains.

Comment: Most VPSes will not let you use them to set up an email server. Too many people have abused email over the past 30 years. You will need to confirm with your provider whether they permit outgoing email traffic from their data centres, otherwise everything you do to configure message signing will be for nothing.